# Pickle Load Model ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'ITYPE_t' but got 'long long'

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, pickle, knn

I got this error "ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'ITYPE_t' but got 'long long'" when I try to load a ML model.

1. I trained a classifier model (knn) and save it on a PC.
2. Then, when I try to test saved model in another PC, I got this error.

**My Code to Save a Model**

```
dill.dump(src_model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

**My Code to load a Model**

```
LOADED_MODEL = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
```

> Also I tried joblib, ubjson, dill and I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`pd.to_pickle(model,r'location-to-store-file/name-of-file.pickle')`
to create a pickle file

`model = pd.read_pickle(r'location-to-store-file/name-of-file.pickle')` to load a pickle file

Comment: I got the samer error; File "sklearn\neighbors\_binary_tree.pxi", line 1180, in sklearn.neighbors._kd_tree.BinaryTree.__setstate__
  File "sklearn\neighbors\_binary_tree.pxi", line 1122, in sklearn.neighbors._kd_tree.BinaryTree._update_memviews
  File "sklearn\neighbors\_binary_tree.pxi", line 236, in sklearn.neighbors._kd_tree.get_memview_ITYPE_1D
**ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'ITYPE_t' but got 'long long'**

Comment: Are you loading the pickle file from your project folder?

Comment: yes, I do. But I also tried to import it from another directory. I got the same error.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Code